# I would like to query a range of criteria on multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, index, select

I have 3 columns in a mysql table. I'm using Innodb engine. I want to be able to search for some values on those columns and also anything close to those values. For example :

We have 3 columns as "Fast" "Smart" "Sharp" and they are of type boolean/int
I have 1000 records in the table, as an example, I list 5 here.

```
Fast  |  smart  |  Sharp
------------------------
0         1          1
1         1          1
0         0          1
1         1          1
1         0          0
```

and let's say we wanna search for people who are smart and sharp as 0  1  1  but if there
is no record with the value of 0  1  1 we want to get the closest to it which is  1  1  1
or 1  0  1 or etc. So now when I search for it, I get the exact value, if the value doesn't
exist, I won't get anything back from DB. So how can I achieve this and if I get a bunch of
result, how can I sort them from the closets to my query to the feartest ?

Comment: This table has not only these 3 columns, it must have at least an `people.id`. Why don't you include the whole table structure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to match against 1 1 1 you could do something like this:

```
set @fast:=1;
set @smart:=1;
set @sharp:=1;

SELECT if(`fast`=@fast,1,0) + if(`smart` =@smart,1,0) + if(`sharp`=@sharp,1,0) as score FROM `table` order by score DESC
```

That should return the exact matches with score 3, people with 2 matches with score 2 and so on.